# Data quality services connection error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools, data-quality-services

I follow this tutorial

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819740(v=sql.120).aspx

for learning SSDT

now when i install first SSDT this setupd "SSDTBI_x86_ENU"  then when i open visual studio and perform all setup but i stuck on task 7  i try to create DQS cleaning connection manager but this shows an error

```
Failed to connect to DQS server the connection manager 'DQS Cleansing Connection Manager.local' as a result of the following value:

A connection could not be made. Ensure that the server is running.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Proxy.Database.DBAccessClient..ctor(IDictionary`2 connectionData)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Proxy.Database.DatabaseMetadataUtility..ctor(String instanceName, Boolean useEncryption)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Component.Common.Utilities.ComponentUtility.GetDQDataBases(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Component.Common.Utilities.ComponentUtility.IsDatabaseExist(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.Component.Common.UI.Common.DataCorrectionForm.ConnectionManagerChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
```

from SQL server configuration manager all services are up and running and when i try to run DQSInstaller from this path

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn

this shows an error

```
    Microsoft (R) DQS Installer Command Line Tool
Copyright (c) 2014 Microsoft. All rights reserved.

[8/1/2017 12:33:06 PM] DQS Installer started. Installation log will be written to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\DQS_install.log


[8/1/2017 12:33:06 PM] Setting the collation to default value: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
[8/1/2017 12:33:06 PM] Failed to connect to local instance 'abc-user'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'CORP\my.name'.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.Ssdqs.DqsInstaller.Utilities.InstallerUtility.TestConnection(String instance, Exception& exception)
ClientConnectionId:13cdade8-344f-43f2-a968-931d2f37fcc5
Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14
Press any key to continue...
```

when i click SQL Server Data quality client and try to connect

this shows an error
[image2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/1105090)

how i resolve this

Comment: is there any solution please

Comment: anyoneeeeeeeeee?